# iOS conditionally declare a property for UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following property declared in my header:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

I'm also using this in an app which needs support back to `iOS 5`. `UIRefreshControl` wasn't added until `iOS6`, so I want to conditionally include it based on the availability of it. I'm aware of the `respondsToSelector` method for checking if a method is available, but how can I do this in the header file where you're declaring your properties? Also, associated methods that used `UIRefreshControl` would have to be conditionally coded.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Would the app crash in iOS 5 just by declaring the UIRefreshControl property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you will be compiling with the iOS 6 or 7 SDK, you can safely include the property in your header, with no negative affects to devices running iOS 5.

As long as you wrap your code conditionally, you won't have issues.

```
// Add pull-to-refresh
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl"))
{
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(startPullToRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview: _refreshControl];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you can probably just declare it as `id` like this:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) id refreshControl;`

When you instantiate it, do it like this:

```
Class refreshClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl");
if(refreshClass){
  _refreshControl = [[refreshClass alloc]init];
}
```